# Change tableview dimensions based on if statement

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to adjust the size of a tableView based on data coming from the previous view controller. For example :

```
if previousData == "Acitivites" {
    tableView.height = 375
    tableView.width = 300
} else {
    tableView.height = 480
    tableView.width = 300
}
```

I'm not sure exactly how to implement this, I would appreciate any guidance!

Comment: unclear what you're asking

Comment: I'd like the table view to fill the entire screen if the data passed in from the previous controller meets a certain criteria. If it doens't meet that criteria, I would like the table view to only take up half of the screen. So I'm trying to adjust the size of the tableview in an if statement.

Comment: Do you have the tableview in storyboard? Are you using constraints?

Comment: Yes the tableview is in storyboard and I do not have constraints at the moment, but I will be adding constraints later.

Comment: so you can achieve this by setting heightConstraint of tableView programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the condition in viewDidLayoutSubviews and change the frame of the tableview.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
    if previousData == "Acitivites" {
        tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 375)
    }
    else
    {
        tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 480)
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing frame in `viewDIdLoad()` is not advisable, please do this in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`

Comment: Why is it wrong to set this in viewdidload? The function described here will be called multiple times, which is not needed

Answer (score 3):

set outlet `heightConstraintTableView` of `tableView`

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
    heightConstraintTableView.constant = previousData == "Acitivites" ? 375 : 480

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set constraint dynamically like below...

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {


    //setting height var
    var height: CGFloat = (previousData == "Acitivites") ? 375 : 480

    //top constraint
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true

    //leading constraint
    tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true

    //trailing constraint
    tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

    //height constraint
    tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true

    //setting height priority to avoid constraint breaking bcoz height, top and bottom is set
    let bottomconstraint = tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor)
    bottomconstraint.priority = .defaultHigh
    bottomconstraint.isActive = true

}
```

If you have created IBOutlet for height constraint then you can set it programatically.

```
self.heightConstraint_tableView.constant = <new height>
```